# how to get table with group by id in bootstrap and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to get Get Record Group wise in Angularjs like below picture please help me this..

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list" id="support_table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="active">

            <th>Voucher Code</th>
            <th>Agent Name</th>
            <th>Ref #</th>
            <th>Arrival Date</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Hotel Name</th>
            <th>In Date</th>
            <th>Nights</th>
            <th>Out Date</th>
            <th>Pax</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="active" ng-repeat="item in VocuharList ">
            <td>{{item.VoucherId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.AgentReference}}</td>
            <td>{{item.ArrivalDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{item.City}}</td>
            <td>{{item.HotelName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.InDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Nights}}</td>
            <td>{{item.OutDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Pax}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

            <td><button id="viewreport" ng-click="AddRoom(item)" type="button" class="btn yellow btn-outline btn-circle btn-xs  m-b-10">View
                    Report</button></td>
            <td><a target="_self">Edit </a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

> i want like this below picture

[image]

> but but current table like below :( i want  group and then show hotel information

[image]

Comment: Which all columns you want to group

Comment: base on voucher id  hotelrecord  show in list above picture

Comment: You can check answer below and let me know if its not working

Comment: its does not show anyrecord when i groupBy : 'VoucherId'

Comment: Can you give the Json you are getting

Comment: i think its not a json problem its table design problem because city ,hotename, indate are in list

Comment: We have to group the Json before sending to ng-repeat thats the problem, I gave answer assuming use have function already to groupBy

Comment: passing simple json that's why show like mt above pic

Comment: It's better if u crate a demo.. So that it's hfpfuk and u get answer quickly

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line as above to group by

```
<tr class="active" ng-repeat="item in VocuharList | groupBy : 'VoucherId' ">
```

And Inject the Angular Filter in the module

`var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);`